# How to install an application in user context in c#

Tags: c#, windows

I've a list of applications that needs to be installed.
Some of them should be installed at user context and others at system context.
I've the code that is working for system context and for user context I'm impresonating the user and executing same method with `INSTALLDIR`, it doesn't throw any error, shows success but app is not installed.

```
        public void InstallPatchWithContext(string context, CatalogPatch patch)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context) && context.Equals(ContextType.User.ToString()))
            {
                WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(GetUserName());
                using (wi.Impersonate())
                {
                    InstallPatch(patch, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                InstallPatch(patch, false);
            }
        }


        public void InstallPatch(CatalogPatch patch, bool userContext)
        {
            try
            {
                string installString = DecodeBase64String(patch.installString);
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(installString))
                {
                    Logger.WriteEntry($"Decoded install string is empty", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    patch.PatchStatus = CatalogPatchStatus.ERROR;
                    return;
                }

                if (!File.Exists(patch.FilePath))
                {
                    Logger.WriteEntry($"Cannot install update:{patch.Name}, file does not exist at path:{patch.FilePath}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    patch.PatchStatus = CatalogPatchStatus.ERROR;
                    return;
                }

                // system context
                ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + installString);

                // user context
                if (userContext)
                {
                    string installDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
                    procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + installString + " INSTALLDIR=\"" + installDir + "\"");
                }
                
                procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(patch.Dir, patch.FolderName);

                Logger.WriteEntry($"Install Args: {procStartInfo.Arguments}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                using (AutoResetEvent outputWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
                using (AutoResetEvent errorWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false))
                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
                    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(1024);
                    StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder(1024);

                    try
                    {
                        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                        {
                            if (e.Data == null)
                            {
                                outputWaitHandle.Set();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                output.AppendLine(e.Data);
                            }
                        };
                        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                        {
                            if (e.Data == null)
                            {
                                errorWaitHandle.Set();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                error.AppendLine(e.Data);
                            }
                        };
                        process.Start();
                        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                        if (process.WaitForExit(ProcessWaitTimeout))
                        {
                            // Process completed
                            if (process.ExitCode == 0 || process.ExitCode == 3010)
                            {
                                Logger.WriteEntry($"Successfully completed installation for update: {patch.Identifier} (ExitCode: {process.ExitCode})", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                                patch.PatchStatus = CatalogPatchStatus.INSTALLED;
                                if (process.ExitCode == 3010)
                                {
                                    // Reboot required
                                    patch.PatchStatus |= CatalogPatchStatus.PENDING_RESTART;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Logger.WriteEntry($"Failed to complete installation for update: {patch.Identifier} using string: {installString}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                                patch.PatchStatus = CatalogPatchStatus.INSTALL_FAILED;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Timed out
                            process.Kill();
                            Logger.WriteEntry($"Failed to complete installation for update: {patch.Identifier} using string: {installString}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                            patch.PatchStatus = CatalogPatchStatus.INSTALL_FAILED;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exp)
                    {
                        Logger.WriteEntry($"Catching {exp.Message} when WaitForExit timed out");
                        patch.PatchStatus = CatalogPatchStatus.INSTALL_FAILED;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        outputWaitHandle.WaitOne(ProcessWaitTimeout);
                        errorWaitHandle.WaitOne(ProcessWaitTimeout);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Logger.WriteEntry($"Error while installing Patch: {patch.Identifier} installation failed, Error: {exp.Message}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                patch.PatchStatus = CatalogPatchStatus.INSTALL_FAILED;
            }
        }
```